# Pass --no-deps in PIP requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I need to pass a flag of `--no-deps` to one of my packages in my requirements.txt file to ignore the dependencies of a package. I've tried putting it above, blow, before, and after the package to no avail. I can do it by itself no problem but not within a requirements.txt file

```
pip install <package> --no-deps
```

requirements.txt

```
<package> --no-deps
```

Comment: I work around this by using two requirements files, and calling pip twice.

`pip install -r requirements.txt` and
`pip install --no-deps -r no_deps.txt`

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately there is no option for this, at time of writing.

The best you can do is freeze everything from your master environment, and use "--no-deps" when you pip install. This is OK since dependencies will be frozen already.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#per-requirement-overrides) you have to write:

```
<package> --install-option="--no-deps"
```

Comment: Why the down-vote? If my answer is wrong, please explain why and improve it or provide the correct answer.

Comment: This passes `--no-deps` to `setup.py` instead of telling pip not to install dependencies for this package.

Comment: `<package> --install-option="--no-deps"` worked for me

Comment: Although documented, this solution doesn't work completely, which is probably a bug or bad design of pip.

Comment: According to pip devs, this is not implemented https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7339

Comment: This is now going to be implemented in https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/10837, so you would just have to do `<package> --no-deps`

Comment: @HarshilMehta Unfortunately this PR appears to have stalled and has not been merged many months later.